# Collision Code isn't working, despite several checks

Tags: c#, xna, collision

I am working on Collision in XNA. Some reason, despite my many tries, it doesn't work. If I touch it, it will work. But sometimes randomly it will just stop running as if a collision occured. The way it works is there are fifty 20px by 20px squares. If your square touches another square in any way, then the game is over.

```
checkcollision()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            if ((loc.X + me.Width > enemyloc[i].X) && (loc.Y + me.Height > enemyloc[i].Y) && (loc.Y < enemyloc[i].Y) && (loc.X < enemyloc[i].X)) { return true; }
            if ((loc.X > enemyloc[i].X) && (enemyloc[i].X + enemy[i].Width > loc.X) && (loc.Y + me.Height > enemyloc[i].Y) && (loc.Y < enemyloc[i].Y)) { return true; }
            if ((loc.X > enemyloc[i].X) && (loc.X < enemyloc[i].X + enemy[i].Width) && (loc.Y > enemyloc[i].Y) && (loc.Y < enemyloc[i].Y + enemy[i].Height)) { return true; }
            if ((loc.X < enemyloc[i].X) && (loc.X + me.Width > enemyloc[i].X) && (loc.Y < enemyloc[i].Y) && (loc.Y < enemyloc[i].Y + enemy[i].Height)) { return true; }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: try using the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this code looks a bit too complicated. I would suggest storing your enemy and player collision boxes as instances of the [Rectangle struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx). The Rectangle struct provides a method called [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447714%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) which is defined as:

```
public bool Contains(int x, int y);
```

This method will return true if the point defined at x and y exists in the rectangle. Thus using this struct the code will become much simpler:

```
public bool checkcollision(Rectangle player)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < enemy.Length; i++)
    {
        if (enemy[i].Contains(player.Left, player.Top)
            || enemy[i].Contains(player.Right, player.Top)
            || enemy[i].Contains(player.Left, player.Bottom)
            || enemy[i].Contains(player.Right, player.Bottom))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you this is actually very helpful

Comment: Your welcome. If you have the time, could you please mark my answer as correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, it's *too hard to read*. While I'm not going to claim it's *the* problem (use a debugger as suggested by Mitch Wheat), it sure could be addressed!

First, lets outline a collision detection for a single axis, X. Instead of looking first for a collision, let's look for *no collision*. There *isn't* a collision along the X axis [only] when "(player to left of enemy) or (enemy to left of player)". (Reason that if neither of these are true then "player on enemy" must be true - use pictures if needed.)

Let p = Player, e = Enemy, then there is a *no collision* [only] when (p.X + p.W < e.X) || (e.X + e.W < p.X). This means that there *is* a collision in the opposite/negated case!

Thus we can write the collision *method*:

```
bool Collides (IEntityBox p, IEntityBox e) {
    bool noCollisionX = (p.X + p.W < e.X) || (e.X + e.W < p.X);
    bool collisionX = !noCollisionX;
    bool noCollisionY = (p.Y + p.H < e.Y) || (e.Y + e.H < p.Y);
    bool collisionY = !noCollisionY;
    // not that the collision on BOTH axises must be fulfilled
    return collisionX && collisionY;
 }
```

Notes (left as an exercise):

1. IEntityBox has X/Y and W/H properties and (0,0) is assumed to the Top-Left corner of the screen. Use the the correct types/propeties for your implementation. It's simpler if the positioning is unified between the player and other entities.
2. The expressions can be rewritten (and De Morgan's can be applied) to clean it up a little bit. Simple collapsing would eliminate all variables and yet keep it "easy" to read.
3. If noCollisionX (which implies !collisionX) is true, we don't need to compute noCollisionY. This could either use an if/else or short-circuit evaluation if collapsed.

Usage is likewise cleaned up:

```
bool PlayerCollidesWithAnyEnemy () {
  foreach (var e in enemies) { // avoid hard-coding numbers
    if (Collides(player, e)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
// ..
var playerOopsed = PlayerCollidesWithAnyEnemy();
```

Or, with LINQ:

```
var playerOopsed = enemies.Any(e => Collides(player, e));
```